# How write in console String text from http get method in JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, get

I have the Rest API on my Spring Boot application:

```
  @CrossOrigin
        @GetMapping()
        public String getText(@RequestHeader(value = "token") String token)
        {
           if (token == "1") {      
             return "Hello world";
           }

           return "511 ";
        }
```

And I have JS Ajax get request on my UI:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function login() {    
    const url = 'http://localhost:8085/api';
    const otherPram= {
    headers: {
     'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'token': 'test'
    },
    method:"GET"
    }

    fetch(url,otherPram).then(res=>{console.log(res)})
   }
    </script>
```

And I want to print in console my return type "Hello world".

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint returns a plain string, so you have to extract the text representation of the response

```
fetch(url, otherPram)
.then(res => res.text())
.then(text => console.log(text));
```

fetch API [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text)